# Как перехватить ошибку в бинарнике?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, cx-freeze

Я в тупике((
Сделал программу в PyCharm, все работает. Сделал компиляцию питон-кода в бинарник с помощью 
cx_Freeze. Все работает до того момента, пока я не запускаю часть скрипта написанную с использованием библиотеки docxtpl, после чего процесс аварийно завершается без каких-либо сообщений. В этой части программы скрипт должен обрабатывать шаблон файла word и сохранять созданный новый файл на диск.

```
    def buttonClicked_docmaker(self):
        self.doc = DocxTemplate("template_AI.docx")
        self.context = {'factory_number': self.fgi.zavnumber} 
        self.doc.render(self.context)
        self.doc.save("D:\\AI.docx")
```

Каким образом можно организовать в исходном коде перехват таких системных ошибок чтобы найти причину?

Comment: Проверь линковку на pyd файлах этого модуля. Библиотеку какую-то сх не докинул

Comment: @eri подскажите плиз какой файл искать? в папке с программой 64 файла .pyd и нет ни одного с именем docxtpl, я в замешательстве

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно данная ошибка была в говнокодере, т.е. во мне! 
Вместо ожидаемого "template_AI.docx" у меня лежал файл "template_AI.doc"

Но по сути вопроса: Как перехватить ошибку в бинарнике? пока ответ - никак.

Comment: А добавьте в код `log_uncaught_exceptions` и попробуйте им поймать ошибку: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3980d329977e05e2c1f95f48b4bbbedeeefe638e/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L35 . Либо, попробуйте в тот метод, где ошибка произошла поставить try/except, скорее всего у вас где-то в слоте произошла ошибка

Comment: ИМХО, просто надо включить логгирование. И обрабатывать все исключения